# Props not being passed or rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello guys I started learning about react, I'm trying to pass the props from one component to another but nothing is being rendered (or console.logged for that matter).

I would more than appreciate your help

Users component

```
export class Users extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { name } = this.props.user;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import { Users } from './users.jsx';

export class WhoWatch extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Choo', series: ['Batman', 'Water'] },
      { id: 2, name: 'Sho', series: ['Boo', 'Too'] },
      { id: 3, name: "Cel'", series: ['Shoo', 'Rima'] },
    ],
  };

  // componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    const { users } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {users.map((user, index) => {
          <div>
            <Users user={user} key={index} />;
          </div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`name` doesn't have a property called `name`:

```
const { name } = this.props.name;
```

Either deconstruct `props`:

```
const { name } = this.props;
```

Or use the property directly without deconstructing:

```
const name = this.props.name;
```

---

**Edit:** It looks like you're confusing a "user" and a "name" in a variety of ways.  Look at what you're passing to the component:

```
<Users user={user.name} />
```

Do you want to pass the user or do you want to pass the name?  The component currently expects a prop called `name`, so pass that:

```
<Users name={user.name} />
```

*Alternatively*, you can pass the whole user:

```
<Users user={user} />
```

And then in the component deconstruct the `user` prop:

```
const { name } = this.props.user;
```

---

Overall it's just a matter of making sure what you're passing and what you're expecting are the same thing.  You might start looking into TypeScript to help enforce this at design time as well.

Comment: Just a small correction, the prop he passed is called `user`, not `name`

Comment: @RonB.: Good catch, updating...

Answer (score 1):

**WhoWatch.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Users from './Users';

class WhoWatch extends Component {
  state = {
    users: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Choo', series: ['Batman', 'Water'] },
      { id: 2, name: 'Sho', series: ['Boo', 'Too'] },
      { id: 3, name: "Cel'", series: ['Shoo', 'Rima'] },
    ],
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.users.map((item) => {
            return <Users user={item} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WhoWatch;
```

**Users.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Users extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
  }
  
  render() {
    const { name } = this.props.user;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Users;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the `WhoWatch` component you pass the user name as value of `user` props on the `User` component not the user object it self.

```
 <Users user={user.name} />;
```

In the `Users` component you are trying to getting the `name` by destructuring the `user` prop which is not an object but a string.

You should just pass the entire User object instead of just the name attribute. As that is the the purpose of that component you should pass the user object like this

```
 <Users user={user} />;
```

And this will solve automatically your issue and as you are in a map every item must have a `key` property like this

```
return (
  <div>
    {users.map((user, index) => {
      <div>
        <Users user={user} key={index}/>;
      </div>;
    })}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answers I've fixed the code but nothing is being rendered still , i editted the code